# Incrementing array values java

Tags: java, arrays, increment

I'm writing a program that allows the user to enter sports teams and then record wins and losses based on the team they enter. I'm fairly certain the way i have the arrays set up is wrong because its not incrementing the wins and losses correctly, does anyone see the issue?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sports {


public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.println("Howdy sports fan!");

    String menuSelect;
    String winSelect;
    String loseSelect;
    int teamSize = 0;

    String[] teamsArray = new String[0];
    int[] winsArray = new int[0];
    int[] lossesArray = new int[0];


    do {

        System.out.println("Please pick an option from the list below:");
        System.out.println("1) Create League");
        System.out.println("2) List all teams");
        System.out.println("3) Record a win");          
        System.out.println("4) Record a loss");         
        System.out.println("5) Quit");          
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        menuSelect = keyboard.nextLine();

        if ( menuSelect.equals("1") )
        {

            System.out.println("How many teams should I make?");
            try
            {
            teamSize = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid entry, try again.");
            }

            teamsArray = new String[teamSize];

            for ( int i = 0; i < teamsArray.length; ++i )
            {
                System.out.println("Team " + (i+1) + "'s name?");
                teamsArray[i] = keyboard.nextLine();                
            }
        }

        else if ( menuSelect.equals("2") )
        {

            if (teamsArray.length == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("There are no teams!");
            }
            else


            System.out.printf("%21s %21s %n", "W", "L");

            for ( int i = 0; i < teamsArray.length; ++i )
            {
                System.out.printf(teamsArray[i] + "%20d %21d %n", winsArray[i], lossesArray[i]);

            }
        }

        else if ( menuSelect.equals("3") )
        {
            winsArray = new int[teamSize];
            System.out.println("Which team won a game?");
            winSelect = keyboard.nextLine();

            for ( int i = 0; i < teamsArray.length; ++i )
            {
                if ( winSelect.equals(teamsArray[i]) )
                {
                    ++winsArray[i];
                }
            }
        }

        else if ( menuSelect.equals("4") )
        {
            lossesArray = new int[teamSize];
            System.out.println("Which team lost a game?");
            loseSelect = keyboard.nextLine();

            for ( int i = 0; i < teamsArray.length; ++i )
            {
                if ( loseSelect.equals(teamsArray[i]) )
                {
                    ++lossesArray[i];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Selection");
        }


    } while(!menuSelect.equals("5"));

}

}
```

Comment: what is input, what is expected result, what is actual result? have you used debugger?

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialise all arrays in Option#1 at a time  instead of initialising in Option#3/4 like this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sports {


public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.println("Howdy sports fan!");

    String menuSelect;
    String winSelect;
    String loseSelect;
    int teamSize = 0;

    String[] teamsArray = new String[0];
    int[] winsArray = new int[0];
    int[] lossesArray = new int[0];


    do {

        System.out.println("Please pick an option from the list below:");
        System.out.println("1) Create League");
        System.out.println("2) List all teams");
        System.out.println("3) Record a win");          
        System.out.println("4) Record a loss");         
        System.out.println("5) Quit");          
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        menuSelect = keyboard.nextLine();

        if ( menuSelect.equals("1") )
        {

            System.out.println("How many teams should I make?");
            try
            {
            teamSize = Integer.parseInt(keyboard.nextLine());
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid entry, try again.");
            }

            teamsArray = new String[teamSize];
            winsArray = new int[teamSize];
            lossesArray = new int[teamSize];

            for ( int i = 0; i < teamsArray.length; ++i )
            {
                System.out.println("Team " + (i+1) + "'s name?");
                teamsArray[i] = keyboard.nextLine();                
            }
        }

        else if ( menuSelect.equals("2") )
        {

            if (teamsArray.length == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("There are no teams!");
            }
            else


            System.out.printf("%21s %21s %n", "W", "L");

            for ( int i = 0; i < teamsArray.length; ++i )
            {
                System.out.printf(teamsArray[i] + "%20d %21d %n", winsArray[i], lossesArray[i]);

            }
        }

        else if ( menuSelect.equals("3") )
        {
            System.out.println("Which team won a game?");
            winSelect = keyboard.nextLine();

            for ( int i = 0; i < teamsArray.length; ++i )
            {
                if ( winSelect.equals(teamsArray[i]) )
                {
                    ++winsArray[i];
                }
            }
        }

        else if ( menuSelect.equals("4") )
        {
            System.out.println("Which team lost a game?");
            loseSelect = keyboard.nextLine();

            for ( int i = 0; i < teamsArray.length; ++i )
            {
                if ( loseSelect.equals(teamsArray[i]) )
                {
                    ++lossesArray[i];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Selection");
        }


    } while(!menuSelect.equals("5"));

}

}
```

Comment: Dont help the person by writing a full code.Tell him his mistakes and let him correct it.
If give a entire code like this the person wont know what will be his mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are allocating the `winsArray` and `lossesArray` whenever you read a win or loss. The following two statements should be in option 1:

```
winsArray = new int[teamSize];
lossesArray = new int[teamSize];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are intializing array like this, the compiler thinkes that these three variables teamsArray, 
winsArray and lossesArray are arraytype with size zero. This means you can add any values in the array and it will result in a error when you try to access like  teamsArray[i].

```
String[] teamsArray = new String[0];
int[] winsArray = new int[0];
int[] lossesArray = new int[0];
```

So try to initialize the array when the user goes for option one to create a league as ravidra said.

```
teamsArray = new String[teamSize];
winsArray = new int[teamSize];
lossesArray = new int[teamSize];
```

Try to learn what went wrong and how to correct it.

Comment: I'm here to learn, some things can be confusing but I see what went wrong in this situation. Thank you for the help